# Find x with $4^{x-1} = 9\cdot x^{3-x}+7$

Tags: exponential-function

How to solve this exponential functuion?

$4^{x-1} = 9\cdot x^{3-x}+7$

The solution is $x=3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equations such as this very rarely have closed-form solutions, and there is no general method for finding them.  In this case it's easy to verify that $x=3$ works.  Using the fact that for $x > 2$, the right side is decreasing while the left side is increasing, it's not hard to show this is the only positive real solution.

Comment: So this is the only way to find the solution?